# Independent and dependent gives the same results?

Tags: statistical-significance, bayesian, chi-squared-test, independence, beta-distribution

Is there any situations where considering two random variables independently and dependently leads to same computational result ? Is there a reason why this might happen ? My specific problem deals with finding $P(p < q)$. In this case, I considered $p$ and $q$ independent and found that the probability as $0.95$. Then I considered them dependent and found the answer as $0.94$. Since both results are approximately the same(this estimation is reasonable), is there a general reason why independence/dependence lead to same result ?

For those interested in the finer details, here is the [link](http://www.cs.hunter.cuny.edu/~saad/courses/bayes/hw/project2.pdf) to the question I am attempting to solve. It is the entire Part 1.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no general reason why independence and dependence will lead to the same result.

For example, suppose the $p$ and $q$ are jointly normal with unit variance, i.e. 
$$ 
\left[ \begin{array}{c} p \\ q \end{array} \right] \sim 
N\left(\left[ \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 2.3 \end{array} \right],
\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & \rho \\ \rho & 1  \end{array} \right]  \right).
$$
In this scenario, the marginal distributions are $p\sim N(0,1)$ and $q\sim N(2.3,1)$.

If $\rho=0$, i.e. $p$ and $q$ are independent, then $P(p<q) \approx 0.95$. But if $p$ and $q$ are not independent, this probability ranges from $\approx 0.88$ to $1$ for $\rho=-1$ to $\rho=1$ respectively.